How the recursive text splitter in langchain works?
While learning text splitter, i got a doubt, here is the code below
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

rsplitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=10,chunk_overlap=0, separators=["\n\n", "\n", " ", ""])

some_text = "Learning new skills is essential for growth"
result = rsplitter.split_text(some_text)
result

The Result is:
['Learning', 'new', 'skills is', 'essential', 'for', 'growth']

My question is how the "skills is" come together and why not "new" and "skills" doesn't?

original_text = "Learning new skills is essential for growth"
"Learning", forms an 8-character long chunk
"new" is 3
"skills is" is 9
Since your chunk_size is 10, the textsplitter is ignoring "new skills" with a length of 10 and storing "new" as its own chunk. Modifying chunk_size to 11 will cause "new skills" to be a chunk.
